# python ttk treeview: Different background or font color for values in item

Tags: python, treeview, ttk

I'm using a ttk treeview  like a table full of testdata and I'd like to highlight now the values which are out of range.

Therefore I'd like to color single values (or the background color of this value) in a item and not the whole item (row).

Is this possible? 
I've found one example where this problem is solved with a treeview per column, but this is not possible, because I don't want to color the whole column, but just one value...
r

Comment: Or any good alternatives? I need the sort function and the table.

Answer (score 1):

The `Treeview` widget doesn't allow you to change the color of individual values.  You can change the color of an entire row, but not just a single value within a row.

Comment: I wonder why not? To my mind it visually unappealing to have the whole row change color